# ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular-bootstrap while installing datetimepicker

Tags: angularjs

I am having this error: ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular-bootstrap when trying to install a datetime picker in angularjs.

I have angular.js 1.2.16 defined on my bower file and the datetime picker seems requiring a newer version of angularjs I guess. I dont know how to fix this problem, is there any way for this to be fixed?

This is my bower.json

```
    {
  "name": "venture",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.16",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.16",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.16",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.16",
    "angular-animate": "1.2.16",
    "angular-touch": "1.2.16",
    "angular-route": "1.2.16",
    "font-awesome": "4.3.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.12.0",
    "oclazyload": "~0.5.2",
    "angular-loading-bar": "~0.7.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.13",
    "angular-toggle-switch": "~1.2.1",
    "metisMenu": "~1.1.3",
    "angular-chart.js": "~0.5.2",
    "satellizer": "~0.13.1",
    "angular-payments": "*",
    "angular-file-upload": "~2.2.0",
    "bootstrap-select": "~1.9.3",
    "ngBootbox": "~0.1.3",
    "angular-ui-tinymce": "~0.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.16",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.16"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.16"
  },
  "appPath": "app"
}
```

I tried using --force it worked on localhost, but when I try to deploy in Heroku it compains and it does not show the timepicker.

Answer (score 0):

In Resolutions, Actually you're installing `1.1.5` with `^`. Please replace it with 1.2.16 here.

```
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.1.5", // change it to 1.2.16
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.16"
},
```

This will solve your problem

Cheers!

Comment: can you please check the version of angular in .bower file inside angularjs?

Comment: what do u exactly mean by this, the version of angularjs is angular": "1.2.16

Comment: "version": "1.5.7",

Comment: From Docs of angular-bootstrap : UI Bootstrap 0.14.3 is the last version that supports Angular 1.3.x.
UI Bootstrap 0.12.0 is the last version that supports Angular 1.2.x. Just to make sure did you remove `^` sign from resolution?

Comment: If you don't mind. can you please delete bower_components and try running `bower install`?

Comment: i deleted and run bower install still the same issue